# Would someone please tell me if I chose the right function?

Tags: java

I'm being asked to find this function:

"Where/what is the code that allows the user to add numbers for the phone number without moving their mouse to get to the next text field? Be specific."

I believe that the function is nextFocusableComponent and is in this class but I just wanted to be sure before I turn it in:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5058644

PhoneFoucusListener class and PhoneDocumentListener class:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5058913

Comment: If you aren't certain it's that method then you certainly don't understand the code. And understanding the code is far more important than your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

these functions move u from the area code, to the prefix, to the suffix

you'll need to explore phonefocuslistener and phonedocumentlistener to see how

```
areaCodeField.addFocusListener(new PhoneFocusListener());
areaCodeField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new PhoneDocumentListener(areaCodeField, 3));

prefixField.addFocusListener(new PhoneFocusListener());
prefixField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new PhoneDocumentListener(prefixField, 3));

suffixField.addFocusListener(new PhoneFocusListener());
suffixField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new PhoneDocumentListener(suffixField, 4));
```

Specifically, this code transfers the focus in the phonedocumentlistener

```
 public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent dEvent) {
    if(dEvent.getDocument().getLength() == numsAllowed)
        txtField.transferFocus();
}
```

Comment: Well, there isn't kind of code like that in the phonefocuslistener class:                                                                 class PhoneFocusListener implements FocusListener {

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fEvent) {
        JTextField tf = (JTextField)fEvent.getSource();
        tf.setText("");
    }
    
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent fEvent){}
    
} 

Same with the other class. Sorry about the format! I'm not sure how to format correctly

Comment: no edit the content. put both PhoneFocusListener and PhoneDocumentListener in there. I almost sure that the code for this is in PhoneDocumentListener. It is being passed an int, which prolly defines how many chars to type until it moves to the next field.

Comment: but I don't have that code inside PhoneFocusListener. Should I post another class?

Comment: you don't need that. you added it to the getDocument() return value. They are two seperate listeners for two seperate purposes. PhoneFocusListener simply clears out the text in the phone field upon selection. PhoneDocumentListener advances to the next field when you hit X number of chars